# Google Maps API for Business - Geocoding requests per second limit?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I know there is a limit of 10 requests per second for the Geocoding API as a normal user.

Does anybody know if this limit is the same, or is increased, or doesn't exist at all for Business users?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are talking about client side Javascript geocoding quota or the server side web service quota.

The client side Javascript does have a quota, but it is a client quota for every user. You get a bunch of requests to start with and then you get a refill every couple of seconds.

The server side  Maps for Business license gets you  10 QPS. The day limits are documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits
You can buy extra QPS by contacting the person you have bought the business license from.

Check out this article:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat
that talks though use cases for client and sever side geocoding if you are still not sure.

If you stick to server side make sure you are using the Geocoding API v3 tho, because v2 is deprecated and will no longer be supported after Mar 8, 2013.

To use Geocoding v3, you need to create digital signatures for each request. Those signatures are generated using a cryptographic key provided to you in the welcome letter you should have received from Google and your client id.

Check out this step by step YouTube video explaining how requests should be signed: http://goo.gl/y7Eq0

If you do not have the crypto key you can get in touch with Google Support and they will send it to you. The form is to contact them is: https://google.secure.force.com/?&hl=en&rd=2